# Confusion about "y1 = tensor @ tensor.T" in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Well, I am new to PyTorch and starting to introduce myself to it from the official website. In there,
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/tensorqs_tutorial.html

it says, for multiplication between two tensors:

```
y1 = tensor @ tensor.T
```

is used where after multiplying two tensors the value is stored in 'y1'. Can you please explain this line and why and how the '@' is used?

Thank You.

Comment: This is a python operator that does matrix multiplication. See [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) for more information.

Comment: ^ Look for `__matmul__`